# Get the metadata for prepared statement in java with MySql DB

Tags: java, mysql, metadata, sqlexception

I want to fetch parameter name and parameter type of given prepared statement. I am using MySQL Database. But when I run my program it is throwing an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for the   given statement
```

at this line

```
String paramTypeName = paramMetaData.getParameterTypeName(param);
```

I don't know why this is happening. Please anybody help me if possible.

Here's my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ParameterMetaData;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = getMySqlConnection();
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

    String query = "select * from survey where id > ? and name = ?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ParameterMetaData paramMetaData = pstmt.getParameterMetaData();
    if (paramMetaData == null) {
      System.out.println("db vendor does NOT support ParameterMetaData");
    } else {
      System.out.println("db vendor supports ParameterMetaData");
      // find out the number of dynamic parameters
      int paramCount = paramMetaData.getParameterCount();
      System.out.println("paramCount=" + paramCount);
      System.out.println("-------------------");
      for (int param = 1; param <= paramCount; param++) {
        System.out.println("param number=" + param);
        String paramTypeName = paramMetaData.getParameterTypeName(param);
        System.out.println("param SQL type name=" + paramTypeName);
      }
    }
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
  }

public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "";
    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

}
```

Comment: Which line throws that `SQLException`?

Comment: String paramTypeName = paramMetaData.getParameterTypeName(param);

Comment: Btw this line is useless `Statement st = conn.createStatement();`

Comment: For which parameter you get that exception (`param` value)?

Comment: hi Bhesh Gurung...i have tried and that is executing fine.

Comment: Can you add more of stacktrace?

Answer (score 13):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

**Should the driver generate simplified parameter metadata for PreparedStatements when no
 metadata is available either because the server couldn't support preparing the statement, or
 server-side prepared statements are disabled?**

You have to set `generateSimpleParameterMetadata` to true

use a connection string similar to this

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true
```

Comment: thanks Bhavik....My code is working after adding "generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true" in the URL but it's giving parameter type "VARCHAR" and in my case, the parameter is "INTEGER".

Comment: when i have given this query :-"select * from test1 where age > ?".

Comment: it's giving parameter type is "VARCHAR". But in my case parameter is "age" and that is "INTEGER" type.

Comment: check it again with the database. It should not happen.

Comment: check with `getParameterClassName(int param) ` what value do you get?

Comment: i got "java.lang.String" value when i am giving getParameterClassName(1)

Comment: type `show columns from test1`  to get the column name and corresponding type in DB

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23490/discussion-between-user591790-and-bhavik-shah)

Comment: I too get parameter type as VARCHAR instead of column specific data type for my prepared UPDATE statement. Any other option to get right  parameter data type?

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL JDBC driver currently does not support it**. I am solving the similar issue and came up with the following workaround:

1. include H2 database in your project (it can also run in embedded mode or in-memory)
2. translate your MySQL create database script to H2 syntax (or write it in ANSI so it is compatible with both)
3. compile prepared statements on H2 database first and get metadata from them - H2 database supports this function and SQL query syntax is similar in most cases - then save the obtained meta information for later use
4. there might be differences in data types, etc, but in general this should give you about 80% match with MySQL without too much hassle

I know it has much caveats, but it might work in some use cases.

Also consider upgrading MySQL database to 5.7, there are some enhancements related to prepared statements which may help, but I am not very deeply knowledgable about those:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepared-statements-instances-table.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html

Answer (score 1):

You have not set the parameter to the prepared statements, without which you cannot get parameter metadata. so first set the parameter

```
pstmt.setInt(val)
pstmt.setString(val)
```

After adding the parameters you can get the meta data about the parameter.

Hope this helps.